# How do I typeset the following using the alignat environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignat

I want to write the equivalent statements as below:
[image]

but I'm having difficulties using the alignat environment to do that. The sample code I'm using is

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    &&gH \in X_0\\ 
    &\iff\quad
    &hgH 
    &= gH \quad \text{for all}\; h \in H \\        
    &\iff \quad
    &g^{-1}hgH
    &=H \quad \text{for all}\; h \in H\\
    &\iff \quad
    &g^{-1}hg
    &\in H \quad \text{for all}\; h \in H\\
    &\iff \quad
    &g^{-1}Hg
    &=H\\
    &\iff \quad
    &gH
    &=Hg\\
    &\iff \quad
    &g
    &\in N_G(H).
\end{alignat*}
```

which produces this

[image]

There has to be a minor change I need to make to make this work so I'd appreciate any help I can get. I realize that I've added `\\` in the code which is giving me a line break, but without it the code wouldn't run so that's why it is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this is the one you need?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
gH \in X_0& \iff\quad
    &hgH 
    &= gH \quad \text{for all}\; h \in H \\     
    &\iff \quad
    &g^{-1}hgH
    &=H \quad \text{for all}\; h \in H\\
    &\iff \quad
    &g^{-1}hg
    &\in H \quad \text{for all}\; h \in H\\
    &\iff \quad
    &g^{-1}Hg
    &=H\\
    &\iff \quad
    &gH
    &=Hg\\
    &\iff \quad
    &g
    &\in N_G(H).
\end{alignat*} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, sir!

Comment: @J.Doe Glad to help you...You're always welcome....